# Overlay problem

Tags: modal-dialogs

When I want to open a content via main menu (e.g. I am in the content "Gallery" and I click on "Article" in the main menu), Drupal first starts to load the article content with overlay on http://www.xxx/galerien#overlay=articles but then it fast loads http://www.xxx/articles.

This happens only to logged in users. It seems the problem is the "Overlay" module and the Workbench module. (Thats the latest module I installed). I don't know why Drupal 7 wants to load the standard content in the admin-overlay.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by, "but then it fast loads `http://www.xxx/articles`"? Do you mean the URL in the address bar changes from `http://www.xxx/galerien#overlay=articles` to `http://www.xxx/articles`?

Comment: It seems the problem is probably not with Workbench, but with a Views/Overlay interaction bug. http://drupal.org/node/1116326

Comment: It seems the problem is the Module "Social Login" when i deactivate it the "overlay-bug" dont appears anymore.